# Larger video is not uploading on s3/paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

paperclip is not uploading video larger then 15 MB on s3 but working fine when changed the path to local server instead of s3

Comment: which error are you getting when you upload?

Comment: nothing, just paperclip stuck at video uploading.
check the console logs: https://ibb.co/G2W7nb2

Comment: If you have server access go to the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and check which value se t to `client_max_body_size`, if no value set  then set it to `client_max_body_size 100M;`

Comment: Tried not working, same result.
Even unable to upload larger files from 15 MB on my local machine.

Comment: Did you restart your server after changing value?

Comment: Yes but not working

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: no just stuck at uploading

Comment: Can't help much without any error . Sorry

Comment: Same issue here brother well Thanks